# The latest Qt 4.8.4

Tags: qt

When downloading Qt4.8.4 from the archives of Digia, is it guaranteed to be the latest with all patches applied? or is this the first Qt484 that ever came out?

how do I get the latest 4.8.4 with patches? will they have it in gitorious? if so, which archive?

Comment: There aren't more than one 4.8.4. When it gets bug fixes, it gets a new version number (4.8.5) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version numbers of released packages would mean nothing if there were any alterations of it. Qt 4.8.4 is exactly the same now as it was a month ago and as it was when it first appeared. That's what "4.8.4" means; it describes *one* specific version. It will *always* be the same, no patches applied and no changes made.

So there is no "latest" Qt 4.8.4. There's only *one* Qt 4.8.4.

Comment: you're right. i meant the latest in the Qt 4.8 branch-  how do I get it?

Comment: @RM1970 See phyatt's answer. To get the current 4.8 Git branch, you just clone the repository with: `git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt`

Comment: not `git clone -b 4.8 git://gitorious.org/qt/qt` ? won't `git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt` just give you the trunk which is now version 5.0?

Comment: @RM1970 Nope. Qt5 is in a different repository (git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git). Btw, I made a typo in my previous comment. The Git URL of the Qt4 repo should be "git://gitorious.org/qt/qt.git".

Comment: @RM1970 Given that my actual answer doesn't really cover all this, I think you should accept phyatt's answer, since that one actually points to the Git repositories. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some links that answer your questions.

http://www.qt.io/download/

http://code.qt.io/cgit/

Hope that helps.